# Using Native HTML5 Drag-And-Drop, how can I make a playing piece occupy multiple table cells?

Tags: html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I'm using Drag and Drop on a table grid. I'm trying to make a playing piece occupy 4 squares of the grid, not a single cell. Currently, the code enables you to successfully drag the div from one cell to another. Now I'd like to double the size of the draggable div so that it occupies 4 cells.

In this example, the cell sizes are fixed at 50x50 pixels. The div is 100x100. Currently, the div expands any cell it occupies, along with the row and column associated with that cell. Rather than expanding the cell, I'd like that div to cover the space of 4 cells.

Essentially, I don't want the div to be contained within the boundaries of a single cell, but to occupy 4 cells. After dragging, when it's dropped the playing piece needs to snap to a cell border.

How can I do this? Below is my code, and a fiddle.

```
<style>
    table td {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .piece {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #09C;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
</style>

<table id="targetTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="piece" id="a" draggable="true">Move Me</div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    initDragAndDrop();
  });

  function initDragAndDrop() {
    $('.piece').on('dragstart', function(event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on('dragenter dragover drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
             var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
             de = $('#' + data).detach();
             de.appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Stormjack/osvu6mea/25/

The current code employs Native HTML5, but I can potentially alter this to use the jQuery library if necessary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't really be done. If the Div is going to be the child of a Cell, it cannot be in 4 cells, it can only be in 1. Now you can make it larger then the parent cell and overflow so that it appears to cover the other 3, but it can only be "in" 1.

Comment: Thanks, Twisty. I just applied position:absolute to the .piece class. And the piece overflows the cell now. It will anchor to a vertical line on drop. But it won't anchor to a horizontal line. See https://jsfiddle.net/Stormjack/osvu6mea/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Absolute positioning, you need a Relative position too.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Ldsaegq2/2/

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

table td {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.piece {
  height: 95px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #09C;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

Dropped item then "sticks" position.

> An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Answer (score 1):

Use colspan property:

```
$(this).attr('colspan',4);
```

So your code will become as:

```
 if (event.type === 'drop') {
        var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        de = $('#' + data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
        $(this).attr('colspan',4);

      }
```

This will make your cell equivalent to 4 cols.

At this stage, you will need to adjust cells. As your table is 4 columns. By assigning colspan=4 to one cell and with extra  cells in the row will make it comprising of 7 columns.  You can find and delete those extra cells.

Comment: That's another interesting approach. Thanks so much, Jawad.